# Javascript regular expression discrepencies

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write some regex that detects a url that ends with a group of numbers followed by a forward slash followed by another group of numbers. When I use something like `\d+\/\d+$` it works fine when testing but not in the console. Example:

`var testRegex = new RegExp('\d+\/\d+$');
testRegex.test('http://somedom.com/somepath/2024/3');`

returns `false` in chrome's console, but finds matches when I use something like https://regex101.com/ or http://regexpal.com/

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
var testRegex = new RegExp('\\d+\\/\\d+$');
```

In a string literal, the JavaScript engine will see `'\d'` as `'d'`. Putting a `\` (backslash) in front of the other `\` (backslash) escapes it and the literal is evaluated to `\d`.

The same applies to `\/` although you could just use `/` instead of `\\/` as you are not using a regexp literal:

```
var testRegex = new RegExp('\\d+/\\d+$');
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I already noticed and corrected it. However, you are incorrect: It is *not* wrong (it would still work), just useless.

Answer (score 2):

Either escape the `\d`s:

```
var testRegex = new RegExp('\\d+/\\d+$');
```

or use a regex literal to avoid double-escapes:

```
var testRegex = /\d+\/\d+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all the backslashes one more time and you don't need to escape the forward slash.

```
var testRegex = new RegExp("\\d+/\\d+$");
```